# window.location is an object?

Tags: javascript

```
window.location = null; // But it redirects to http://example.com/null
```

is it possible to delete window.location?

I am writing a proxy and I want to make sure the the script inside the  request url won't redirect to their page.

```
window.location = 'http://actual-urlexample.com';
```

My idea is to replace the *window.location* with our object so that we can control the above code for my proxy sever. I want to know only one thing: whether *window.location* is an object or not. How an event(new url is loading) occurring when we assigning a value to *window.location*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're at least two obvious ways to find out:

- Your browser's JavaScript console:

  ```
  >>> typeof window.location
  "object"
  ```
- Your favourite [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location):

  > Returns a [`Location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Location_object), which contains information about the URL of
  >   the document and provides methods for changing that URL. You can also
  >   assign to this property to load another URL.

<sub>No offense but I'd like you see you overriding a builtin object if you even need to ask whether it's an object ;-P</sub>

**Edit:** A little clarification—I suppose that technically speaking `location` is actually a *property* of the `window` object that contains a `Location` object.

Comment: and looking at `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,"location")` its `configurable` property descriptor is (of course) set to `false` 
(+1)

Comment: We cannot make window.location null. why it is not possible if it is a normal object? How can you technically call it is a property since window.location as an property href (window.location.href)? I am not expert in JavaScript. That is why I got the doubt. Some project requirements lead as to override even build in object.

Comment: @habeebperwad - See Glutamat's comment.